# Is it possible to create "stored procedure c#" like "stored procedure java" in trafodion

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I am using Trafodion to work in HBase by transnational sql queries.I saw java files(stored procedure) are using by "Call" operation so is it possible to create "stored procedure c#" like "stored procedure java" for Call operation.
                                                          kindy forgive me for any mistakes in my question i am freasher in programmer field

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Trafodion has stored procedures in Java. The Trafodion community is working on a manual that describes how to do it, so currently there isn't a simple and easy set of instructions. Here is a simple example that takes three SQL strings as arguments and creates three result sets for them.

First, write a Java program like this:

```
import java.sql.*;

class TEST101
{
  public static ResultSet makeRS(String s, int i) throws Throwable
  {
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(s);
    return ps.executeQuery();
  }

  public static void rs3(String s1, String s2, String s3, String[] status,
                         ResultSet[] rs1, ResultSet[] rs2, ResultSet[] rs3)
    throws Throwable
  {
    status[0] = "OK";
    rs1[0] = makeRS(s1, 1);
    rs2[0] = makeRS(s2, 2);
    rs3[0] = makeRS(s3, 3);
  }
};
```

Second, compile it (use Java 7) and create a jar file for it. Make sure you have the .../core/sqf/export/lib/trafodion-sql-*.jar file in your CLASSPATH:

```
javac TEST101.java
jar cvf TEST101.jar *.class
```

Third, create a library from the jar file in Trafodion, then create the actual stored procedure:

```
create library TEST101 file '/your directory/TEST101.jar';

create procedure rs3(in query1 char(1000),
                     in query2 char(1000),
                     in query3 char(1000),
                     out status char(70))
language java parameter style java reads sql data dynamic result sets 3
external name 'TEST101.rs3' library TEST101;
```

Last, call the stored procedure

```
create table test101_t1(a int no heading, b int, c char(10));
insert into test101_t1 values (1, 100, 'first'), (2, 200, 'second');

call rs3('select * from test101_t1',
         'values (''second'', ''rowset'')',
         'values (current_user)',
         ?);
```

Hope that helps. Sorry nobody from the Trafodion community saw this earlier. By the way, you can also email user@trafodion.incubator.apache.org with questions.